# Accessing Firefox cookies via ff-addon-sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to access the cookies of a website opened in a specific tab through the firefox-addon-sdk.

Sorry, for the general question, I'm not able to find anything on the web about it.

Is someone able to give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) module to get to the tab and attach a content script to it to do as you please (such as accessing cookies). See the section "Run Scripts in a Tab" or, for more, the tutorial it references: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/modifying-web-pages-tab.html

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Am I able to access ALL cookies via document.cookie inside the tab environment?

Comment: Yes, it should as the SDK is running in a privileged environment.

Comment: My guess would be no because the script is running in the tab environment - but I'm not sure. Has anyone tested this?